# Issues with Ports on headless service attached to Stateless Set

Tags: kubernetes, informix, minikube, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-statefulset

Hi I am trying to expose 5 ports for an Informix Container which is within a statefulSet. It has a headless service attached, to allow other internal stateless sets communicate with it internally.

I can ping the headless service `informix-set-service` from my `informix-0` pod and other pods however when I try `nmap -p 9088 informix-set-service` the port is listed as closed. I am assuming this is because my yaml is wrong but I can't for the life find out where it's wrong.

It appears that the headless service is indeed attached and pointing at the correct stateful-set and within the minikube dashboard everything looks and appears to be correct.

[Service minikube dash screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdW5M.png)

```
informix@informix-0:/$ nmap -p 9088 informix-set-service

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2019-08-20 03:50 UTC
Nmap scan report for informix-set-service (172.17.0.7)
Host is up (0.00011s latency).
rDNS record for 172.17.0.7: informix-0.informix.default.svc.cluster.local
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
9088/tcp closed unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
informix@informix-0:/$ nmap -p 9088 localhost

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2019-08-20 03:50 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00026s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
PORT     STATE SERVICE
9088/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

Anyone got any ideas?

## Deployment yaml snippet:

```
###############################################################################
# Informix Container
###############################################################################
#
# Headless service for Informix container StatefulSet.
# Headless service with clusterIP set to NULL
# create DNS records for Informix container hosts.
#
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: informix-set-service
  labels:
    component: informix-set-service
    provider: IBM
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 9088
    name: informix
  - port: 9089
    name: informix-dr
  - port: 27017
    name: mongo
  - port: 27018
    name: rest
  - port: 27883
    name: mqtt
  selector:
    component: informix-set-service
---
#
# Service for Informix container StatefulSet service.
# This is used as an external entry point for 
# the ingress controller.
#
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: informix-service
  labels:
    component: informix-service
    provider: 4js
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9088
    name: informix
  - port: 9089
    name: informix-dr
  - port: 27017
    name: mongo
  - port: 27018
    name: rest
  - port: 27883
    name: mqtt
  selector:
    component: informix-set-service
---
#
# StatefulSet for Informix cluster.
# StatefulSet sets predictible hostnames,and external storage is bound
# to the pods within StateFulSets for the life.
# Replica count configures number of Informix Server containers.
#
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: informix
  labels:
    app: informix
    component: db
    release: "12.10"
    provider: IBM
spec:
  serviceName: informix
  #replicas: 2 #keep it simple for now...
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: informix-set-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: informix-set-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: informix
        image: ibmcom/informix-innovator-c:12.10.FC12W1IE
        tty: true
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        env:
        - name: LICENSE
          value: "accept"
        - name: DBDATE
          value: "DMY4"
        - name: SIZE
          value: "custom"
        - name: DB_USER
          value: "db_root" 
        - name: DB_NAME
          value: "db_main"
        - name: DB_PASS
          value: "db_pass123"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9088
          name: informix
        - containerPort: 9089
          name: informix-dr
        - containerPort: 27017
          name: mongo
        - containerPort: 27018
          name: rest
        - containerPort: 27883
          name: mqtt
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /opt/ibm/data
        - name: bind-dir-mnt
          mountPath: /mnt
        - name: bind-patch-informix-setup-sqlhosts
          mountPath: /opt/ibm/scripts/informix_setup_sqlhosts.sh
        - name: bind-file-dbexport
          mountPath: /opt/ibm/informix/bin/dbexport
        - name: bind-file-dbimport
          mountPath: /opt/ibm/informix/bin/dbimport
        - name: bind-file-ontape
          mountPath: /opt/ibm/informix/bin/ontape
        - name: bind-file-informix-config
          mountPath: /opt/ibm/data/informix_config.custom
        - name: bind-file-sqlhosts
          mountPath: /opt/ibm/data/sqlhosts
      volumes:
      - name: data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: ifx-data
      - name: bind-dir-mnt
        hostPath:
          path: <PROJECTDIR>/resources/informix
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
      - name: bind-patch-informix-setup-sqlhosts
        hostPath:
          path: <PROJECTDIR>/containers/informix/resources/scripts/informix_setup_sqlhosts.sh
          type: File
      - name: bind-file-dbexport
        hostPath:
          path: <PROJECTDIR>/containers/informix/resources/bin/dbexport
          type: File
      - name: bind-file-dbimport
        hostPath:
          path: <PROJECTDIR>/containers/informix/resources/bin/dbimport
          type: File
      - name: bind-file-ontape
        hostPath:
          path: <PROJECTDIR>/containers/informix/resources/bin/ontape
          type: File
      - name: bind-file-informix-config
        hostPath:
          path: <PROJECTDIR>/containers/informix/resources/informix_config.custom
          type: File
      - name: bind-file-sqlhosts
        hostPath:
          path: <PROJECTDIR>/containers/informix/resources/sqlhosts.k8s
          type: File
---
```

**Edit 1: (added output of ss -lnt)**

```
informix@informix-0:/$ ss -lnt
State       Recv-Q Send-Q              Local Address:Port                Peer Address:Port
LISTEN      0      0                       127.0.0.1:9088                           *:*
LISTEN      0      0                       127.0.0.1:9089                           *:*
LISTEN      0      0                      172.17.0.7:27017                          *:*
LISTEN      0      0                      172.17.0.7:27018                          *:*
LISTEN      0      0                      172.17.0.7:27883                          *:*
LISTEN      0      0                               *:22                             *:*
LISTEN      0      0                              :::22                            :::*
```

Comment: Have you checked which pod is associated with 172.17.0.7 and run the nmap locally there? Also, check `ss -lnt` inside the pod to make sure the port is listening on all interfaces, not just 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Hi, 172.17.0.7 is the `informix-0` pod which is associated with the informix statefulset and the nmap output above is from running it local on `informix-0`. Running it on a different pod associated with a different stateful set returns the same result.

I added the output of ss -lnt in an edit above.

Comment: Based on that `ss` output looks like @BMitch’s hunch was correct, it’s only bound to port 9089 for 127.0.0.1 IP, which is why it works locally but not between pods. Depends on how this informix container image takes configuration and starts processes.

Comment: Might need to look into User Provided sqlhosts. https://github.com/informix/informix-dockerhub-readme/blob/master/12.10.FC12/informix-innovator-c.md. Looks like your mounting a hostPath at the necessary location for that, what’s in that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `ss` output, you are listening on 127.0.0.1, rather than all interfaces:

```
informix@informix-0:/$ ss -lnt
State       Recv-Q Send-Q              Local Address:Port                Peer Address:Port
LISTEN      0      0                       127.0.0.1:9088                           *:*
LISTEN      0      0                       127.0.0.1:9089                           *:*
```

You need to adjust your application configuration to listen on something like `0.0.0.0` to enable it to be accessed from outside of the pod.

Comment: yep. Thanks this was the issue. 

To anyone having a similar issue and not just with informix. Having a process listen on localhost won't work with a headless service when connected to a stateful set. Setting it to listen on `0.0.0.0` will make it listen on all interfaces or set it to listen on it's own hostname. **With informix specifically** I had to set the `SQLHOSTS` file to effectively listen on `$(hostname)` #informix-0 < pod name

Comment: You can also replace the hostname (3rd column in the Informix SQLHOSTS file) with a '*' (for example: ol_informix1410 onsoctcp * ol_informix1410). That way the server will spawn a listener thread for each network interface.

Comment: nice, didn't know that. Thanks @jsagrera